# How to list usb devices in my android application?

Tags: android

is there a way/api to list all the usb devices plugged in ? Thanks a lot =]

Comment: Assuming you mean USB devices attached to your phone (and not phones connected to your computer by USB), the latest version (3.1) appears to offer very broad USB support: http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html

However I don't think there are any 3.1 devices yet. I don't think there's any official USB support in current Android versions but there may well be something just under the covers - it is Linux after all.

Answer (score 0):

This command is used to list all attached devices. `adb devices`

```
    C:\Users\XYZ>adb devices
                 List of devices attached
                 emulator-5554   device
                 10008f960534    offline
```

Comment: sure it's the most convenient way to get the list, but actually I want to implement it programmly =]